# Payment make a request how to translation to other page

Tags: magento2, payment

```
 public function placeRequest(TransferInterface $transferObject)
   {


    //make a request
    $tranferBody  = $transferObject->getBody();
    $postData['appid']      = 'wxd678a7b9c9cea774';
    $postData['key']        = '1235142d77e4a3a244f0072c4f92d2ed';
    $postData['mch_id']     = '123456';
    $postData['orderName']  = '454ds';

    $outTradeNo             = $tranferBody['INVOICE'];
    $totalFee               = $tranferBody['AMOUNT'];

    //post data
    $postDataXml            = $this->createOrderData($postData,'http://www.baidu.com',$outTradeNo,$totalFee);
    $this->logger->debug(['xml'=>$postDataXml]);
    $this->curl->post($transferObject->getUri(),$postDataXml);

    $response   = $this->curl->getBody();//response data
```